# Android 10+ (API 29+) connect to Wi-fi in background programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi

In my Flutter app, I'm using native Android code (in Kotlin) to connect to a specific Wi-Fi programmatically. For Android 10+, I need to use network specifier. It works, **but only if an app is in foreground**. In background, I always end up in `onUnavailable` callback.

In my specific use case, the app connects to a highly unstable Wi-Fi (it turns off and on all time). I need the app to be able to reconnect without any user interaction even with the display turned off.

Is there a way to connect to a specific network in background?

```
val specifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .setSsid(ssid)
                .setBssid(MacAddress.fromString(macAddressString))
                .apply {
                  if (isWpa3 != null && isWpa3) {
                    setWpa3Passphrase(password)
                  } else {
                    setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                  }
                }
                .build()

var request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
              .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
              .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
              .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
              .build()


this.networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

      override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        super.onAvailable(network)
        connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
       
        // Success
      }

      override fun onUnavailable() {
        super.onUnavailable()

        // Unavailable
        
        // Always end up here with display off
      }

    }
    // Defined elsewhere
    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback)
```

Comment: Hey, have you ever managed to resolve your issue?

Comment: I made a workaround with Service https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification) I setup the service to check the current SSID regularly and fireup the network request when the current ssid doesn't match. Service is able to get the network even when the app is running in background and display is off.

Comment: Great - I came to a little bit similar solution. I started a foreground service and this fortunately allowed me to stay connected.